# Power App writeback in Power BI with Smartsheet

Tags: powerbi, smartsheet-api, powerapps-canvas

I'm trying to use Power App embedded in Power BI to writeback data source from Smartsheet. However, I was not able to choose any of the sheets that has been listed from the newly created form in Power App and the "Add Field" option was disabled. I wonder if I need extra Smartsheet connector in this case or it is because I don't have admin access to Smartsheet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPs74.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljYv2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've never personally used Power Apps with Smartsheet, but I'd suggest you start by reviewing the following info.

Info about the integration between Power Apps and Smartsheet (including capabilities of integration):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/smartsheet

Step-by-step walkthrough for configuring the integration between Power Apps and Smartsheet:

- https://www.theblueflamelabs.com/microsoft-powerapps-and-smartsheet-integration

If this info doesn't unblock you, then I'd suggest you ask a question in the Smartsheet Community:

- https://community.smartsheet.com/post/question/apps-and-integrations

(Stack Overflow is a place to ask coding how-to (Smartsheet API) questions, whereas the Smartsheet Community is the place to ask questions about using the app (where questions don't necessarily involve coding or the Smartsheet API).